# SQL Query: How to select one key column distinct but second column value all obtained

Tags: sql, ms-access

sorry for very simple question, I want to query the results where the key should be displayed once but other column values need to be obtained entirely.

This is my table value:

```
file_num    key_num
14719       74787
14719       74789
14719       74978
14720       74790
14720       74791
14720       74792
14720       74793
```

`file_num` is a key. The expected result is:

**14719**       74787       74789       74978
**14720**       74790       74791       74792       74793

Where `file_num` only appears once and `key_num` which have similar `file_num` are organized in one row.

Thanks in advance, your suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

K

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? DB2?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I use MS Access. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible until you wrap all `key_num` values in one row with `LIST` or something like this. Unless you provide us with more information, like if there is a specified number of `file_num` cause there would appear `JOIN` for each `file_num`.

Answer (score 0):

This VBA function might do what you want: http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html

You'd use it like this:

```
SELECT CompanyName,  ConcatRelated("OrderDate", "tblOrders", "CompanyID = " & [CompanyID]) 
FROM tblCompany;
```